# How to remove a Spot Fleet Request after it is cancelled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So, I have accidentally created a Spot Fleet Requests with bad configuration and immediately cancelled it. Now I have these Spot Request rows displayed as `(-) cancelled`  (all instances were terminated with it):

[image: Cancelled SFR]

How do I get rid of these cancelled entries? I couldn't find a `Delete` button anywhere and I do have sufficient permissions AFAIK.

Comment: Probably you can't. They can be removed by aws after some time, just like terminated instances.

Comment: That's my guess too. I'll keep checking occasionally and update if they'll go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to delete them manually, but they'll disappear automatically after some time. In my case it took around 24 hours. So [Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248823/marcin)'s comment is correct

Answer (score 0):

Not really 24 hours. My cancelled requests have not been disappeared even it's over 2 days.